# Why were the workers opposed to Hitler becoming the chancellor of Germany near the end of the Weimar republic?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, hitler, nazism, weimar-republic

I just started reading " The rise and fall of the third Reich " by Shirer and came across paragraph stating a hundred thousand workers opposed Hitler becoming the chancellor. If Hitler was the head of the Socialist party why were the workers opposed. Isn't a socialist form of government something the workers would want?

Here's the excerpt from the book:

> The wildest rumors of what might happen were rife in the capital that fateful winter weekend, and the most alarming of them, as it happened, were not without some foundation. There were reports that Schleicher, in collusion with General Kurt von Hammerstein, the Commander in Chief of the Army, was preparing a putsch with the support of the Potsdam garrison for the purpose of arresting the President and establishing a military dictatorship. There was talk of a Nazi putsch. The Berlin storm troopers, aided by Nazi sympathizers in the police, were to seize the Wilhelmstrasse, where the President’s Palace and most of the government ministries were located. There was talk also of a general strike. On Sunday, January 29, a hundred thousand workers crowded into the Lustgarten in the center of Berlin to demonstrate their opposition to making Hitler Chancellor. One of their leaders attempted to get in touch with General von Hammerstein to propose joint action by the Army and organized labor should Hitler be named to head a new government.1 Once before, at the time of the Kapp putsch in 1920, a general strike had saved the Republic after the government had fled the capital.

Comment: Re: "If Hitler was the head of the Socialist party why were the workers opposed" From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazism) (my bolding): "Nazism [...] the common name in English for **National Socialism**, is the **far-right** totalitarian political ideology and practices associated with Adolf Hitler and the Nazi Party (NSDAP) in Nazi Germany." IMHO, it would be beneficial to work out a contextual overview (Wikipedia is *one* possible starting point) before doing a deep dive on Shirer's book. General speaking, we like questions here to demonstrate a modicum of research effort.

Comment: One issue which I might have expected to be addressed in your post is how the abstract ideologies of socialism align with the concrete realities of Hitler's party as described in the paragraph that you quote.

Comment: Hitler was extremely opposed to Communism.  The two competing extremist parties in Germany were Nazis and Communists.  It would seem rather obvious that Communists, with their traditional focus on class warfare and worker proletariat could mobilize demonstrations against Hitler.  Who would in fact disenfranchise Communist parliamentarians later.  Is this another one of our frequent, *"But, but, Nationalsozialistische Deutsche Arbeiterpartei means the Nazis were lefties, weren't they?"* questions?  Those are generally held to be mostly aimed to discredit left leaning political views.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I think the modern notions of *right* and *left* did not apply in those times... indeed, the perception of fascists/Nazis as extreme right and Communists as extreme left likely grew out of their final confrontation in WW2. In 1930-s Communists and Nazis were certainly both anti-liberal radicals, which had a lot in common... but Nazis were never Marxist. They were both socialists, but in a different sense of this word... and in senses different from how it is understood by mainstream modern left wing.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica yeah I also

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica yeah I also read the communist manifesto, I understand they just cooperated now and then when their motives aligned especially the communists. But going as far as to unite with the Weimar republic to oppose them when in many instances their ideologies do align especially considering that the communism of Germany was different from that of France\Russia. I thought nazi were more in favour of the workers than the republic was and yet they still supported the republic.Is this wrong or were the leaders of the workers plain desperate and didn't want Hitler at the helm?

Comment: @ShadowNik *workers* is an ambiguous term - some of them were communists, some nazis, and some simple social Democrats. Note also that German communists were not a single party - historically SDP adhered to Marxism, but it largely abandoned it by the times of Weimar, while the hardcore communists split over the stance of the war credits before WW1. Note also that *Communist Manifesto* was written when Marx and Engels were just approaching their 30-s - despite its popularity, it very approximately represents Marxism.

Comment: Congrats on reading Shirer - just in the process of rereading it myself.  A primer on Nazis to follow along with might be [Rest is History podcast](https://www.listennotes.com/podcasts/the-rest-is-history/295-the-rise-of-the-nazis-YUPz87HheVj/).  [Wages of Destruction](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/711592) is a deep exposition of Nazi economics.  Your Q, and wish to dig deeper, isn't necessarily bad, but we really do have a lot of baggage here with people arguing Nazi==Left, on repeat, which is why the reception isn't very friendly.

Comment: As to German/French Communists being different:  no, that is wrong.  Back then the main Communist parties (not the Trotskyists) were in the thrall of Moscow.  Quite a few members of the Parti Communiste Francais were expelled in 39 upon protesting Molotov Ribbentrop for example.

Answer (score -1):

> If Hitler was the head of the Socialist party why were the workers opposed. Isn't a socialist form of government something the workers would want?

*Socialism* is a very broad and vague term:

- **Marxism**  Sometimes *Socialism* serves as a proxy for *Communism*, which in itself is usually a proxy for *Marxism*, i.e. the ideology grounded in the writings of Karl Marx (Marx himself often used terms *Socialism* and *Communism* interchangeably, although later Communists tend to associate Socialism with a historical stage between Capitalism and Communism.)
- **Liberal socialism** In many places *Socialism* is a designation for *social democracy*, i.e. *welfare capitalism* - a capitalist system augmented with redistribution of wealth, in order to help those who are less fortunate and/or in need. This is how it is understood in modern Europe. Note however, that European states tend to call themselves *Social* rather than *Socialist* - the latter term being used officially mainly by the USSR and its satellites. Many liberal democratic parties however call themselves *Socialist* - sometimes they trace their roots to pre-Marxist socialist movements (like the French Socialist Party or various Democratic socialists in the UK), in some cases they are former Marxist parties that abandoned the revolutionary Marxist orthodoxy and opposition to parlamentary democracy and liberalism, and sometimes a mix of both (like the German SDP, which traces its origins to Ferdinand Lassalle, but also to a pro-Marxist Eisenacher movement.)
- **Other**  In some cases *Socialism* is also used as a catch-word for helping average people, whatever is the rest of the ideology - this is how it was used by National-Socialists.

Shirer mentions the young Göbbels' opinion that Nazis shared objectives with the German Communists and should have collaborated with them. However, National-Socialists never subscribed to the Marxist ideology, and Göbbels himself later went on to draw the distinction between the two in his pamphlet *Nazi-Sozi*. Claiming that Nazis were *opposed* to Communsits is somewhat misleading - they did oppose them as their political rivals in Germany, and Hitler's plans for expansion to the east necessarily brought Nazis in opposition with Stalin's Soviet Union. However, without the collaboration between Hitler and Stalin in 1939-1941 the history of Nazism and the World history might have been very different. Not in the least, the Communists took early on a habit of calling *fascist* any of their opponents - real fascists, liberal capitalists, European socialists opposed to the Soviet repressions and even each other (like Yugoslav communists after the break with Stalin or Khrushchev after disavowing Stalin's *cult of personality*), thus greatly exaggerating the opposition.

Nazis also opposed to the liberal form of Socialism - their objective being creation of a state under the leadership of a single Leader and single party.

National-socialism was indeed a popular movement aiming at redistribution of wealth, and as such it could be termed *socialist*. Once Hitler was in power, he found an accomodation with the leading German industrialists, while many in the movement still believed that "the National-Socialist revolution" was not over (mostly the infamous Brown shirts.) This resulted in the [Night of the long knives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Long_Knives). Still, even afterwards the Nazi movement conserved many of its socialist and even collectivist features in terms of workers organization, children summer camps, etc. Furthermore, Nazis largely followed through with the Keynesian economic policies they inherited from Weimar republic - the German equivalent of the New Deal in the US, which assured the [*Nazi economic miracle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtschaftswunder).